# Sort by date the items

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, tkinter, attributes

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to do a program that gets the homeworks and organize them by date, being the closest date first. The problem is that I've been looking a way to organize the homeworks but I cannot find the way.

This is what I have so far, by the moment I get

```
line 70, in escribirTarea
    archivo.write(elemento+"\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk
from datetime import date, datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry

lista= []

def guardar():
    nt= nombreTarea.get()
    a= asignatura.get()
    t= tarea.get()
    f= fechaEntrega.get()
    lista.append([nt, a, t, f])
    escribirTarea()
    messagebox.showinfo("Guardado", "La tarea ha sido añadida")
    nombreTarea.set("")
    asignatura.set("")
    tarea.set("")
    fechaEntrega.set("")
    consultar()

def eliminar():
    eliminado= contEliminar.get()
    remove= False
    for elemento in lista:
        if contEliminar.get()==elemento[0]:
            lista.remove(elemento)
            removido= True
    escribirTarea()
    consultar()
    if removido:
        messagebox.showinfo("Completado", "Tarea borrada" + eliminado)

def consultar():
    r = Text(ventana, width=80, height=15)
    lista.sort()
    valores= []
    r.insert(INSERT, "Nombre tarea\t\tAsignatura\t\tDescripción\t\tFecha\n")
    for elemento in lista:
        arreglo= elemento
        valores.append(elemento)
        r.insert(INSERT, arreglo[0]+"\t\t"+arreglo[1]+"\t\t"+arreglo[2]+"\t\t"+arreglo[3]+"\t\n")
    r.place(x=20, y=250)
    spinNombreT= Spinbox(ventana, value=(valores), textvariable=contEliminar).place(x=340, y= 212)
    if lista==[]:
        spinNombreT= Spinbox(ventana, value=(valores)).place(x=340, y= 212)
    r.config(state=DISABLED)

def iniciarArchivo():
    archivo= open("ot.txt", "a")
    archivo.close()

def cargar():
    archivo= open("ot.txt", "r")
    linea= archivo.readline()
    if linea:
        while linea:
            if linea[-1]== "\n":
                linea= linea[:-1]
            lista.append(linea)
            linea= archivo.readline()
    archivo.close()

def escribirTarea():
    archivo= open("ot.txt", "w")
    lista.sort()
    for elemento in lista:
        archivo.write(elemento+"\n")
    archivo.close()
    
lista.sort(key = lambda element: datetime.strptime(element[3], '%d %m %Y'))

ventana= Tk()
nombreTarea= StringVar()
asignatura= StringVar()
tarea= StringVar()
fechaEntrega= StringVar()
contEliminar= StringVar()
colorFondo= "#5f99f5"
colorLetra= "#fff"
iniciarArchivo()
cargar()
consultar()
ventana.title("Recuerda tu tarea")
ventana.geometry("700x500")
ventana.configure(background=colorFondo)
etiquetaTitulo= Label(ventana, text="Ingresa tus tareas", bg=colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 16)).place(x=260, y=10)
etiquetaNTarea= Label(ventana, text="Nombre de tu tarea:", bg= colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=60, y=50)
cajaNTarea= Entry(ventana, textvariable=nombreTarea).place(x=200, y=52)
etiquetaAsignatura= Label(ventana, text="¿Qué materia es?", bg= colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=60, y=80)
cajaAsignatura= Entry(ventana, textvariable=asignatura).place(x=200, y=82)
etiquetaTarea= Label(ventana, text="Descripción de tarea:", bg= colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=60, y=110)
cajaTarea= Entry(ventana, textvariable=tarea).place(x=200, y=112, width= 300)
etiquetaFechaE= Label(ventana, text="Fecha de entrega:", bg= colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=60, y=140)
cajaFechaE= DateEntry(ventana, textvariable=fechaEntrega).place(x=200, y=142)
botoGuardar= Button(ventana, text="Guardar", command= guardar, bg="#0f6bfc", fg="white").place(x=200, y=170)
etiquetaEliminar= Label(ventana, text="Ingresa el nombre de la tarea que terminaste:", bg= colorFondo, fg=colorLetra, font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=60, y=210)
spinNombreT= Spinbox(ventana, textvariable=contEliminar).place(x=340, y= 212)
botonEliminar= Button(ventana, text="Completado", command= eliminar, bg="#0f6bfc", fg="white").place(x=485, y=208)
mainloop()
```

Comment: I think that `lista` is a list of lists, so the line `archivo.write(elemento+"\n")` inside `escribirTarea()` function is trying to concatenate `elemento` (a list) and "\n" (a string).  May be what you need is `",".join([str(x) for x in elemento])+"\n"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your list `lista` does not contain string values but lists since you append lists to this list in the `guardar()` function: `lista.append([nt, a, t, f])`. You can't add a string to a list by addition.

In the function `cargar()` you just read the lines of the file as strings and add them to `lista`. You could load a file with this function and store it again with `escribirTarea()`. But since you change the contents of `lista` while sorting, your data type changes and you can't just write the values anymore.

One workaround would be to create a second list that contains the dates in a sortable format (e.g. Unix timestamps) and is as long as `lista`. Then you can sort your `lista` by temporarily zipping these lists without ever changing an element. That would make more sense.